# javascript window.open() and # symbol

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I am trying to link to a file that has the '#' character in via a window.open() call.  The file does exist and can be linked to just fine using a normal anchor tag.

I have tried escaping the '#' character with '%23' but when the window.open(myurl) gets processed, the '%23' becomes '%2523'.  This tells me that my url string is being escapped by the window.open call changing the '%' to the '%25'.

Are there ways to work around this extra escaping.

Sample code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function escapePound(url)
{
   // original attempt
   newUrl = url.replace("#", "%23");
   // first answer attempt - doesn't work
   // newUrl = url.replace("#", "\\#");

   return newUrl;
 }
</script>
<a href="#top" onclick="url = '\\\\MyUNCPath\\PropertyRushRefi-Add#1-ABCDEF.RTF'; window.open(escapePound(url)); return true;">Some Doc</a>
```

URL that yells says "file://MyUNCPath/PropertyRushRefi-Add%25231-ABCDEF.RTF" cannot be found

Comment: Can you give an example of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seek the dark magicks of [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp):

```
window.open("http://your-url.com/" + encodeURIComponent("foo#123.jpg"));
```

Comment: This did it.  Not sure why this wasn't working for us earlier.  Thanks.

Comment: Figured out why it wasn't working earlier.  Needed to first open the window then on the returned object change the location.href to the escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the standard text escape char "\"?

```
\#
```

Comment: Just tried that. The url called is then gets closer, but still fails.  Updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried URL encoding via JavaScript as done [here](http://cass-hacks.com/articles/code/js_url_encode_decode/) and [here](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not escaping the url?

```
<a href="#top onclick="url = '\\\\MyUNCPath\\PropertyRushRefi-Add#1-ABCDEF.RTF'; window.open(url); return true;">Some Doc</a>
```

Comment: The not escaping is no good since the URL stops at the # symbol due to it being a special URL character